# setxkbmap -option lv3:ralt_switch_multikey doesn't work with many layouts

Tags: xorg, locale, xkb

My current xkb setup is as follows:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     us,cz(qwerty)
options:    lv3:ralt_switch_multikey,grp:lalt_lshift_toggle
```

When in the `us` layout, a combination of right shift and right alt works as the compose key (also called multi key). When in the `cz(qwerty)` layout it doesn't do anything.

I also tried to switch to a much better layout for me as a czech/english writing programmer and I was told about `us(cz_sk_de)`. Unfortunately compose key doesn't work for that layout either.

I suspect it is related to the number of levels used in a keyboard layout as both failing layouts offer additional characters using right alt. What is the best way around?